# How to retain the hint text in android EditText field?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my android app, I have a hint text in my EditText view. Once the user starts typing, I want the hint to be displayed on top of the edittext field. The original hint text disappears when user starts typing which is fine. How do I place a text on top of the edittext field ? Is there a way to make the EditText field multiline and use the first line for hint? But the user input should always start from the second line. [image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

- Just found that they are called floating inline labels in android.
  http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels
  But looks like API 21 doesnt support this yet.

Comment: Add a text view above and set it to gone or invisible. When user starts typing, set the tv visibility to visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FloatLabelLayout](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/11247418). It's a custom component that works as described in the google documentation.

Once you create the custom component you can use it in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <your.package.FloatLabelLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:floatLabelTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.YourApp.FloatLabel">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/account_username_hint"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edit_password" />

    </your.package.FloatLabelLayout>

    <your.package.FloatLabelLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:floatLabelTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.YourApp.FloatLabel">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/account_password_hint"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

    </your.package.FloatLabelLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

There new widget provide by android called **TextInputLayout** it is the standard way. Below is an example of it:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <EditText
          android:id="@+id/first_edit_text"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="hello"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: There is a problem with this answer when typing the text, the hint disappearing. I am using 26.0.2